# Dashboard prompt scope set to page but affects other pages

Tags: obiee

I have set scope to page and want the prompts not to affect other pages. But it affects the other pages despite the scope set to page.

There are 3 prompts on each page, first prompt on page 1 asks for year, first prompt on page 2 asks for year and month (separate), when i choose year on page 1 and when i go to page 2 the prompt and table+diagram has been affected, they have basically the same filters, but for what I understand that when scope is set too page that shouldnt happen.

Have i understood the scope setting wrong or is this a bug? I am running OBIEE on version 11.1.1.7.160119

The funny part is that I have a second dashboard with the same setting and it works there!? I have also tested changing the prompt and filter like this "Dimension"."Year" + 0 and that works but I dont really want to do that if there is a better solution for this. Maybe I have missed something in some settings somewhere.

Comment: The prompts sets the analysis and diagrams if asked in the filters, but does the prompts get set by the analysis or diagrams? Just wondering when I set the prompts in one page and the analysis in that page is affected, can the analysis affect the prompts? Wondering if its not the prompts but maybe the analysis that are spooking my dashboard

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know why it might happen, the only thing that comes to my mind is maybe you are using Presentation Variables in your prompts, so when you set the presentation variable in one prompt it affects the other prompt because you are using the same presentation variable.
Regards

Comment: No nothing like that, I use a SQL to get the data for the list and they have different variables for default value, but i dont use any presentation variables